# onException leads to infinite loop during route

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have this `onException` block before my route

```
onException(Exception.class)
        .process(new IncProcessor(IncService))
        .handled(true);
```

What the processor does is grab the exception that occurs and uses an API to send and store it where I want it. The problem is that when that `IncProcessor` experiences an error, it results in an infinite loop since the `onException` block catches the error that occurs in `IncProcessor` and tries to run that same processor again. Is there any way to get around that?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your error processing logic in a usual `try/catch` block avoiding `IncProcessor` errors to clutter your route business errors:

```
public class IncProcessor implements Processor {

    public void process(Exchange exchange) {
        try {
            // process the exchange error
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // swallow, log, or process the exception somehow
        }
    }
}
```

One neat way of handling this, avoiding to throw away the `Exception-Processor` errors, would be to

Define a new sub-`Exception`:

```
public class IncProcessingException extends RuntimeException {
    // ...
}
```

Wrap the error in a well-defined one:

```
public class IncProcessor implements Processor {

    public void process(Exchange exchange) {
        try {
            // process the exchange error
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IncProcessingException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Define a custom *redelivery policy* for the processing exception:

```
onException(IncProcessingException.class)
    .maximumRedeliveries(1);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @tmarwen. One question i have though is where would i put that onException(IncProceesingException.class) code? Would it go on top of my own onException block?

Comment: It can go wherever you want in your routes / endpoints configuration.

Comment: @tmarven Can you clarify a little more? Would I add it to my current onException block like so? 
```
  onException(IncProcessorException.class).maximumRedeliveries(1)
        .onException(Exception.class)
        .process(new IncProcessor(IncService))
        .handled(true);
```

Comment: @CrisManrique, no, you should add it as a second "onException" block, next to the one you already have, at the same level. What tmarwen meant is that it doesn't matter whether it goes before it or after it, or even after your route definitions (although that last option would definitely be less readable).

Comment: @LaurentChabot I've tried that and added a ```.stop``` at the end of the onException block to stop the exchange, but it keeps trying to execute it which results in an endless loop again. 
```
    onException(IncProcessingException.class)
        .handled(true)
        .stop();

    onException(Exception.class)
        .process(new IncProcessorService(IncProcessor))
        .handled(true);
```

Comment: What endless looping do you still observe exactly? You should check (print or log or debug or whatever) what exception is being received by your IncProcessor (exchange.getException()). Normally it can never be an instance of IncProcessingException. So your endless loop, if present, is of a different nature.